# Get cumsum from aggregated field with Django orm

Tags: django, sqlite

In my project, I want to get the sum of an "amount" field which comes form an aggregate. I've read some posts on this but I can't find a way to achieve what I want.

**Example model:**

```
class ScheduledOperation:
   day = models.dateField()
   amount = models.DecimalField(...)
```

**Example queryset**

```
{'day': datetime.date(2023, 2, 7), 'amount': Decimal('-500.00')} # same day each month
{'day': datetime.date(2023, 2, 7), 'amount': Decimal('1500.00')} # same day each month

{'day': datetime.date(2023, 3, 7), 'amount': Decimal('-500.00')}
{'day': datetime.date(2023, 3, 7), 'amount': Decimal('1500.00')}

{'day': datetime.date(2023, 4, 7), 'amount': Decimal('-500.00')}
{'day': datetime.date(2023, 4, 7), 'amount': Decimal('1500.00')}

{'day': datetime.date(2023, 5, 7), 'amount': Decimal('-500.00')}
{'day': datetime.date(2023, 5, 7), 'amount': Decimal('1500.00')}

{'day': datetime.date(2023, 5, 8), 'amount': Decimal('-4000.00')} # big op here
```

**Where I am so far**

`ScheduledOperation.objects.order_by('day').values('day').annotate(day_tot=Sum('amount'))` gives me the total amount for each day:

```
{'day': datetime.date(2023, 2, 7), 'day_tot': Decimal('1000')}
{'day': datetime.date(2023, 3, 7), 'day_tot': Decimal('1000')}
{'day': datetime.date(2023, 4, 7), 'day_tot': Decimal('1000')}
{'day': datetime.date(2023, 5, 7), 'day_tot': Decimal('1000')}
{'day': datetime.date(2023, 5, 8), 'day_tot': Decimal('-4000')}
```

**What I want**

```
{'day': datetime.date(2023, 2, 7), 'day_tot': Decimal('1000'), 'cumul_amount':Decimal('1000')}
{'day': datetime.date(2023, 3, 7), 'day_tot': Decimal('1000'), 'cumul_amount':Decimal('2000')}
{'day': datetime.date(2023, 4, 7), 'day_tot': Decimal('1000'), 'cumul_amount':Decimal('3000')}
{'day': datetime.date(2023, 5, 7), 'day_tot': Decimal('1000'), 'cumul_amount':Decimal('4000')}
{'day': datetime.date(2023, 5, 8), 'day_tot': Decimal('-4000'), 'cumul_amount':Decimal('0')}
```

**What I tried**

After reading other related posts on this subject, I've tried to use the `Window` function:

```
self.coming_scheduled_ops.order_by('day').values('day').annotate(
    day_tot=Sum('amount')
).annotate(
    cumul_amount=Window(
        Sum('amount'),order_by='day'
    )
)
```

but this does not work:

```
{'day': datetime.date(2023, 2, 7), 'day_tot': Decimal('1000'), 'cumul_amount': Decimal('1500')}
{'day': datetime.date(2023, 3, 7), 'day_tot': Decimal('1000'), 'cumul_amount': Decimal('3000')}
{'day': datetime.date(2023, 4, 7), 'day_tot': Decimal('1000'), 'cumul_amount': Decimal('4500')}
{'day': datetime.date(2023, 5, 7), 'day_tot': Decimal('1000'), 'cumul_amount': Decimal('6000')}
{'day': datetime.date(2023, 5, 8), 'day_tot': Decimal('-4000'), 'cumul_amount': Decimal('2000')}
```

I can't use `Window(Sum('day_tot'))`, it throws `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot compute Sum('day_tot'): 'day_tot' is an aggregate`

Could someone help me understand the `Window` function plz?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that's possible using Django ORM, but you can easily do this using Python.

```
queryset = ScheduledOperation.objects.all()
queryset = (
    queryset.order_by('day')
    .values('day')
    .annotate(day_tot=Sum('amount'))
)
cumul_amount = 0
for day in queryset:
    cumul_amount += day['day_tot']
    day['cumul_amount'] = cumul_amount
```

It results in:

```
{'day': datetime.date(2023, 2, 7), 'day_tot': Decimal('1000'), 'cumul_amount': Decimal('1000')}
{'day': datetime.date(2023, 3, 7), 'day_tot': Decimal('1000'), 'cumul_amount': Decimal('2000')}
{'day': datetime.date(2023, 4, 7), 'day_tot': Decimal('1000'), 'cumul_amount': Decimal('3000')}
{'day': datetime.date(2023, 5, 7), 'day_tot': Decimal('1000'), 'cumul_amount': Decimal('4000')}
{'day': datetime.date(2023, 5, 8), 'day_tot': Decimal('-4000'), 'cumul_amount': Decimal('0')}
```

Comment: Yes sure, and this might be the best solution in fact. I was trying to avoid doing this to have everything done in one databse call. A friend explained to me that it is not always a good idea to add load on the database requests, and I might do as you said.

Comment: After i posted this answer i tried with using [Lag function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/database-functions/#lag) Didn't really got anywhere, but maybe that's something to check